# AngularJS - Correctly formatting asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

newbie here.

I am trying to understand how I need to structure asynchronous calls within my controller to fit my specific use case:

Consider the following code snippet from an Angular Module in "service.js" within my project:

```
function getSearchObjects(projectName, title) {
    var payload = JSON.stringify({
        "title": title
    });

    var request = $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: URL + '/search/' + projectName,
        data: payload
    });
    return request.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
};

function runQuery(projectName, fromDate, toDate, sort, direction, columns) {
    var from = Date.parse(fromDate);
    var to = Date.parse(toDate);

    var payload = JSON.stringify({
                                    "fromDate": from,
                                    "toDate": to,
                                    "sort": sort,
                                    "direction": direction,
                                    "columns": columns
                                });
    console.log(payload);
    var request = $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: URL + '/query/' + projectName,
        data: payload
    });
    return request.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}

function handleSuccess(response) {
    return response.data;
};

function handleError(response) {
    if (!angular.isObject( response.data ) || !response.data.error) {
        return( $q.reject( "An unknown error occurred." ) );
    }
    return $q.reject( response.data.error );
};

});
```

Within my controller, I am trying to troubleshoot the following function:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  var objectProperties = exportsStorageService.getSearchObjects($scope.selected.project.name, $scope.selected.search)
    .then(function(result) {
        exportsStorageService.runQuery($scope.selected.project.name, $scope.selected.start_date, $scope.selected.end_date, objectProperties.sort, objectProperties.direction, objectProperties.columns)
    },            
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

getSearchObjects matches a title ($scope.selected.search) selected in my UI and grabs the following more detailed object from an API call:

```
{ title: 'Duplication Example',
sort: '#_traac-timestamp',
direction: 'desc',
columns: [ '#_traac-remote_ip', 'c-platform-m-distinct-id_s', '_type' ] }
```

I am trying to grab the properties returned from getSearchObjects and pass them along with a few user selected values from my UI to runQuery, which then returns data from a database to the user, but when I check the values passed to runQuery using the above logic in my controller, I get the following values. All of the objectProperties values I am attempting to pass to runQuery are undefined:

```
project_name: "Example Project"
start_date: 1499770800000
end_date: 1499943600000
sort: undefined
direction: undefined
columns: undefined
```

I have been trying to debug this, but I am too new to using Angular and asynchronous calls to really understand what I am doing wrong. My best guess currently is that I am calling runQuery before the values retrieved from getSearchObjects are attached to objectProperties. Either that or I am incorrectly referencing the properties within the objectProperties variable.

Could someone help me troubleshoot this issue, and better understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var objectProperties = some async function...
```

You are assigning **the promise** of the async function to the variable, **not the result of it**.

The result is coming in the `.then`, like you declared:

```
.then(function(result) { ... }
```

So, instead of `objectProperties.sort, objectProperties.direction, objectProperties.columns`, try using `result.sort, result.direction, result.columns` :)

If you are new to Promises, take a look at this [simple, but great tutorial](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises).

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you are receiving, inside the response.data, the following object:

```
{"objectMatch": {
    "title": "doc-event",
    "sort": "#_traac-timestam‌​p",
    "direction": "desc‌​",
    "columns": [
                 "m-doc-‌​name_s",
                 "m-user_s",
                 "‌​m-full-action-type_s‌​",
                 "m-event-action-de‌​scriptor_s"
               ]}
}
```

So you have: *response > data > objectMatch > properties you want*.

The response.data you are extracting on your `handleSuccess` function:

```
function handleSuccess(response) {
    return response.data;
};
```

So here, your `result` is `response.data`, containing the property `objectMatch`.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  var objectProperties = exportsStorageService.getSearchObjects($scope.selected.project.name, $scope.selected.search)
    .then(function(result) {
        ...
    },
    ...
```

If all of that is correct, you should be able to access the values you want using `result.objectMatch.<sort, direction or columns>`, like:

```
exportsStorageService.runQuery($scope.selected.project.name, $scope.selected.start_date, $scope.selected.end_date,
    result.objectMatch.sort, result.objectMatch.direction, result.objectMatch.columns)
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I tried your proposed solution, but the three result properties are still coming back undefined :( any other ideas? I have been stumped on this all afternoon...

Comment: @JoeyMarinello What is your request made from `getSearchObjects` returning? Take a look at the "Network" tab on the Chrome Developer Tools if you are unsure how to debug it.

Comment: `{"objectMatch":{"title":"doc-event","sort":"#_traac-timestamp","direction":"desc","columns":["m-doc-name_s","m-user_s","m-full-action-type_s","m-event-action-descriptor_s"]}}`

That's the response I get.

Comment: @JoeyMarinello edited my answer based on your comment.